# Django Form Not Appearing

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I'm new to Django and am using the code on [this](http://collingrady.wordpress.com/2008/02/18/editing-multiple-objects-in-django-with-newforms/) page in my app. I'm trying to write a template to show the `Poll` form and the `Choices` form (as specified on the website), but only the `Poll` form appears. Below is my template code:

```
<form action="/new/" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
{{ poll_form.as_p }}
{{ choice_forms.as_ul }}
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Any advice is much appreciated.

Comment: Can you add the rest of the code in your view and form?

Answer (score 0):

If you're following the view code given in the link you posted, 'choice_forms' is actually a list of form objects. Thus calling 'as_ul' will have no effect. You'll have to try something like the following:

```
{% for choice_form in choice_forms %}
    {{ choice_form.as_ul }}
{% endfor %}
```